# Firebase API initialization failure

Tags: push-notification

I tried using FCM first time(No prior experience of GCM). So, i just copied code from [quickstart-android-push-notifs](https://github.com/ritesh-goel/quickstart-android/tree/master/messaging) and set-up the dashboard

as i send a message from dashboard, the app force closes, here are related files

---

app level build.gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.+'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
}
```

logs:

```
08-22 22:59:38.360 12349-21221/com.rg.fcmsample E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-2-thread-1
                                                              Process: com.rg.fcmsample, PID: 12349
                                                              java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzz(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzaa; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzaa' appears in /data/data/com.rg.fcmsample/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.google.android.gms-play-services-basement-9.4.0_893226f39952d5ea4f5509d84b650028d7d5f6b4-classes.dex)
                                                                  at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzx.zzbd(Unknown Source)
                                                                  at com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                                  at com.google.firebase.messaging.zzb.zzes(Unknown Source)
                                                                  at com.google.firebase.messaging.zzb.zzc(Unknown Source)
                                                                  at com.google.firebase.messaging.zzb.zzl(Unknown Source)
                                                                  at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzn(Unknown Source)
                                                                  at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzm(Unknown Source)
                                                                  at com.google.firebase.iid.zzb$2.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
08-22 22:59:49.015 12349-21221/com.rg.fcmsample I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 12349 SIG: 9
08-22 23:00:10.549 21506-21506/com.rg.fcmsample W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.rg.fcmsample-2/lib/arm
08-22 23:00:10.764 21506-21506/com.rg.fcmsample W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.rg.fcmsample-2/lib/arm
08-22 23:00:10.799 21506-21506/com.rg.fcmsample D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping initialization.
08-22 23:00:10.817 21506-21506/com.rg.fcmsample D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
08-22 23:00:10.887 21506-21506/com.rg.fcmsample E/FirebaseApp: Firebase API initialization failure.
                                                               java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzek(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1748)
                                                                   at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1723)
                                                                   at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5174)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4769)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4709)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:154)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1415)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
                                                                Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzz(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzaa; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzaa' appears in /data/data/com.rg.fcmsample/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.google.android.gms-play-services-basement-9.4.0_893226f39952d5ea4f5509d84b650028d7d5f6b4-classes.dex)
                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzx.zzbd(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source) 
                                                                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
                                                                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
                                                                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzek(Unknown Source) 
                                                                   at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source) 
                                                                   at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1748) 
                                                                   at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1723) 
                                                                   at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5174) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4769) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4709) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:154) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1415) 
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
08-22 23:00:10.889 21506-21506/com.rg.fcmsample I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
```

what's wrong?

Comment: Did you add the google-services.json file to your project?

Comment: looks like you have not added google service in your project gradle file.

Comment: @DavidCorral i added google services in project. 
By mistake i added apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' at the beginning. adding it at last (as mentioned in tutorials) solved the problem.

Comment: still it gives the same problem in some devices

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should insert this code on build.gradle

"compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'

I am fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

on build.gradle dependencies firebase-messaging and play-services must be same version:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    ...
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'` into your bulid.gradle